# Selecting all element on page but all element inside an element with an id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to bind a click event to all the element on a page except to those inside an element with an id

```
    $('body :not(#dialog-form *)').off('click').on('click', function (e)
    {
     //code
    });
```

The above mentioned code binds the click event to those elements inside 'dialog-form'.

Comment: Rather than binding to everything, you could use `.on` to bind to a high-level element (perhaps `body`), and ignore events occurring on specified elements.

Comment: Do as @MikeW suggested. Binding an event to every element is a huge performance hit. It's simpler if you add a class name to the elements you do not want the event bound to. Then you can do this: `$('body').on('click', ':not(.class-name)', function () { /* do stuff */ });`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is working but you missunderstand what happen. You see, you bind a click on everything except some elements, but `#dialog-form *` is inside `body` which mean that even if `#dialog-form *` has no event, a click on it will proc a click on `body` (which contain an event). You need to prevent the bubbling:

```
$('body').off('click').on('click', function (e){
    //code
});

$('#dialog-form').on('click', function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/d4gLd/

Comment: Gotcha! but I want the event handler for the elements inside 'dialog-form' to fire their events!

Comment: I don't see why it would stop them!

Comment: 'cuz of 'e.stopPropagation();'

Comment: stop propagation is on `#dialog-form`, so elements inside it will still be fired!